# Fire function after all views have been loaded in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple divs responsible for different parts of view and one which is a overlay for all of them (#loading-div). I want the loading div wait until all the views are loaded and then disappear, however it does not work as expected. Please see the code below.

HTML

```
<div id="content-wrapper" ng-controller="UAMController as uamCtrl">
    <div id="left-column" ng-include="uamCtrl.leftColumnTemplate"></div>
    <div id="middle-column" ng-include="uamCtrl.middleColumnTemplate"></div>
    <div id="right-column" ng-class="{'active': uamCtrl.middleColumnTemplate}" ng-include="uamCtrl.rightColumnTemplate"></div>
    <div id="loading-div" ng-init="coreCtrl.loadingBlock()"></div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
self.loadingBlock = function () {
    $('#loading-div').fadeOut();
}
```

Could you please help me to the issue to make the div appear right after everything else in the wrapper is loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked out the run phase in the angular initialization? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run . Specifically, it will run after angular is done initializing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 try below code in your controller.. $viewContentLoaded event will be fire after all DOM is loaded to the browser.

 $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    $('#loading-div').fadeOut();
 });
```

Comment: I have added $timeout service and it does what I was expecting from the function :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$includeContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude#$includeContentLoaded), which as the documentation state is...

> Emitted every time the ngInclude content is reloaded.

Then you can listen for this event every time the `ngInclude` is updated:

```
$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event) {
     $('#output').append('<p>' + event.targetScope.name + ' include\'s content was loaded.</p>');
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimSangwine/Tzg49/) for demonstration.

Comment: I think $viewContentLoaded not waits for the content load of all the ng-include views. Use $includeContentLoaded is right, but if you need wait for many ng-includes and you don't know which is the lastest, maybe you need wait for all as I said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422003/angular-directive-how-to-make-sure-all-nested-templates-and-partials-loaded/44805254#44805254

Comment: You just saved my day !! :) Thank you ;)